# Bits apear twice in size_t

Tags: c++, bit

This might be a very stupid question, so please be gentle. If I run the following code:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef uint64_t obs;

int main () {
    printf("Size : %i\n",sizeof(obs)*CHAR_BIT);

    obs value = 1 << 3;
    printf("Number: %zu\n",value);

    printf("Bits : ");
    for (size_t ind = 0; ind < sizeof(obs)*CHAR_BIT; ind++) {
        if (value & (1 << ind)) {
            printf("%zu ",ind);
        }
    }
}
```

For various typedefs I get the following result for 64 bit datatypes (I run on a 64Bit system):

uint64_t / size_t / long unsigned

```
Size : 64
Number : 8
Bits : 3 35
```

and the following for other lengths:

uint32_t / uint16_t / uint8_t

```
Size : 32 / 16 / 8
Number : 8
Bits : 3
```

If if changing the shift the 64Bit type seems to have a "mirror counterpart" which is shifted by 32Bit. The same holds true when I change the value of value. Is there a reason for this or am I missing something?

using gcc on Win7

Comment: `1 << ind` is not working as you'd hoped because the 1 is a 32-bit integer... change to `1LL << ind` and you won't see bit 35 in your output.

Comment: Use `%d` or `%i` for `int`, `%zu` for `size_t`. For `uint64_t`, either use the macro in `<inttypes.h>` whose name I don't remember, or cast to `uintmax_t` and use `%zu`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, well yes obviously you're right. I didn't change this for every data type. Maybe I should have gone with `cout` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size_t is architecture dependant so on a 32-bit system size_t will likely be at least 32-bits wide. On a 64-bit system it will likely be at least 64-bit wide.

According [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an
>   unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other
>   headers)

Also change

```
if (value & (1 << ind))
```

to

```
if (value & (1LL << ind))
```

as 1 is a 32-bit integer

Comment: Ah ok, this means if I'm using any literal it makes automatically a 32Bit number even though I'm on a 64Bit system?

Comment: @magu_ using a 64-bit OS doesn't mean that your program also is a 64-bit one, that depends on the target settings

Comment: @magu_ An integral literal has type `int` if 1) it fits in an `int` and 2) it has no suffix.  So `1` will have the number of bits in an `int`; on most current implementations, this is 32 bits, but there are exceptions.

Comment: @JamesKanze, this is what I love about this site. You alway learn something new. Thank you.

Comment: I found your C99 Standard quote pretty confusing... it would help to provide the context that it's referring to the results of the `sizeof` operator (or better yet, quote from the C++ Standard given the question's tags).  Cheers.